# Can't downgrade composer to version 1 and can't install elasticsuite on Magento 2.4.0

Tags: linux, composer-php, magento2

I'm trying to install elasticsuite 2.10.1 on Magento 2.4 but I need to downgrade my composer to version 1 but I keep getting stuck.

When I try to downgrade to composer to version 1 with `composer self-update --1`

```
[Composer\Downloader\FilesystemException]
  Filesystem exception:
  Composer update failed: "/usr/local/bin/composer" could not be written.
  rename(/home/usr/.cache/composer/composer-temp7912166.phar,/usr/local/bin/composer): Permission denied
```

Adding `sudo` results in `sudo: composer: command not found`
I've also installed composer globally and moved the `.phar` file to `/usr/local/bin/composer`

I've also ran `composer update --no-plugins` and it returns with the following:

```
  Problem 1
    - Root composer.json requires dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer ^0.5.0 -> satisfiable by dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer[v0.5.0].
    - dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer v0.5.0 requires composer-plugin-api ^1.0 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
  Problem 2
    - laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.4] require composer-plugin-api ^1.1 -> found composer-plugin-api[2.1.0] but it does not match the constraint.
    - magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 requires laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin ^1.0 -> satisfiable by laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin[1.0.0, ..., 1.0.4].
    - Root composer.json requires magento/product-community-edition 2.4.0 -> satisfiable by magento/product-community-edition[2.4.0].
```

I've tried googling for answers and no luck for the last 2 hours, I'm out of ideas on how to resolve the problem

Comment: Why not update the dependencies instead? `dealerdirect/phpcodesniffer-composer-installer` has a version that is compatible with Composer v2 (while v0.5.0 is three years old!). `laminas/laminas-dependency-plugin` can be used since Magento 2.4.2 (available since Feb 2021)

Comment: @NicoHaase im going to give those a try, I believe I've tried that already with no luck

Answer (score 0):

If you **really** want to use Composer v1 (which is deprecated and won't be around forever!), you need to run the downgrade with `sudo` in front to avoid permission problems.

Comment: i've already tried the sudo, its mentioned in the original post -thanks though

Answer (score 0):

The following works for me:

First, check the requirement for composer and php version here:
https://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.4/install-gde/system-requirements.html

Remove the vendor folder

Assume you are using composer 2, for Magento 2.4.0 - 2.4.3-P2, run:

```
sudo composer self-update --1
```

Run the followings:

```
sudo yum install php php-{pear,cgi,common,ctype,curl,fileinfo,mbstring,gd,hash,iconv,sockets,sodium,tokenizer,xmlwriter,xsl,mysqlnd,gettext,bcmath,json,xml,fpm,intl,zip,imap,dom,simplexml,soap,libxml,openssl}

sudo composer install
```